# WxGrid get selection cells and getcellvalue

Tags: wxwidgets

i want to `GetCellValue` based on `GetSelectedCells. I've this code :

```
wxGridCellCoordsArray cells = Grid1->GetSelectedCells();
```

I want to use `cells` to be the parameter for `GetCellValue` so i can get the selected cell value. 
How to do that? 
I'm using codeblocks and c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wxGrid` doesn't store data, it's a view-and-controller class, but the model, storing data, is a table class derived from `wxGridTableBase`, which you can retrieve using `wxGrid::GetTable()`. You can then use its `GetValue()` and similar functions.